# How to calculate the probability of scenario for 2 dependent events?

Tags: math, probability

Imagine a duel between two man: **A** and **B**. The probability **A** will kill **B** is **Pa**, for **B** is **Pb**. How to calculate the probability that **A** win?
Example:

```
**A** chances to kill **B** is 30
**B** chances to kill **A** is 50

Then **A** chances to win is: 46
```

`46` is correct, but I have no idea how it was calculated.
[Source of the task](http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/duel-chances)
Could someone point the direction?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A goes first, so wins with p=3/10 (exclusively) or doesn't with p=0.7.
If that happens B has a go, and wins with p=0.5. If he doesn't win, A has another go, and wins with p=0.3 still. And so on. Exclusive events means we can add the possibilities.
A wins 0.3 + (0.7*0.5)**0*0.3 if he wins on either the first.
A wins 0.3 + (0.7*0.5)**1*0.3 if he wins on either the first or second go.
A wins 0.3 + (0.7*0.5)**2*0.3 if he wins on either the 1st, 2nd or 3rd go.
The chance of A winning is the sum of these.


In general we get

```
p(A wins) = (0.7*0.5)**n *0.3 for n=0..inf
```

This is a geometric series for (0.7*0.5), so has sum 1/(1-(0.7*0.5)) which is around 1.53

The final answer is the chance of A winning, with 0.3 so is

```
0.3*1.0/(1-(0.7*0.5))
```

which is 0.4615... or about 46%

This isn't a coding question though.
Details of how to get the formula for a geometric series are clear on [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html).
Drawing a decision tree might help.

Comment: I can't understand why using the formula with `**A** chances to kill **B** is 20` and `**B** chances to kill **A** is 15` I do not get the answer `63` (which is correct). `0.2/(1-(0.8*0.75))=0.5` I put the variables into formula correctly, didn't I?

Comment: So, 20 and 15 are the next values given in the problem if I follow the link. Giving 0.2 * 1.0/(1-(0.8*0.85))
                 ^-------------
Note two thing. Multiply p(A wins) by the the other chances. You have divide. Also, P(B does not kill A) = 1.0 - 0.15 = 0.85 NOT 0.75